# How much it cost to use Amazon S3 for Video Streaming backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

We are developing a video streaming site

For that we want to use Amazon S3 storage

But I can't understand the pricing structure . The price calculator is also confusing

Please tell how much it will cost for below calculation

100 Videos uploaded via S3 Api .. Each having size of 500 MB.(Region LONDON)

```
=> So 100 x 500 = ~ 5GB storage used
```

each and every video requested (GET) 1000 times

```
=> 100 * 1000 = 100,000 GET requests
```

each and every video viewed 1000 times

```
=> So (500 x 1000) x 100 = ~ 5 TB bandwidth used
```

---

Now please say how much it will cost ? deduce the pricing step by step

Comment: S3 is only mean for intermediary storage, it is not a delivery medium. You must use CDN together (e.g. cloudflare, cloudfront) to cut the data delivery cost.

Comment: What is the difference between a "request" and a "view" in your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS has an [official pricing tool](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) which is helpful for estimating a service cost.

The estimate for your S3 cost is: $448.69 / month

[image]

You can see the full workings, and update the calculation [here](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#r=LHR&s=S3&key=calc-BB7C8231-0F77-444D-9357-6FA1831F1414).

Comment: Indeed, traffic is expensive (it's not just AWS, all could provides are having cca  0.1 eur / GB). I believe with IBM Cloud you could prepay some traffic packages saving cca 20%

Comment: thanks . Yes. This is very expensive !! @thomasmichaelwallace

Comment: One more help thomasmichaelwallace &  @gusto2 .. Please suggest a good cloud service provider with low cost for my above mentioned need

Comment: @LordCommander Check out https://peervadoo.com/ . It can reduce video streaming costs by more than 90%

Answer (score 2):

100 Videos uploaded at 500mb each:

100 * $0.23 / 2 = $1.15

Each video requested 1,000 times:

(100 * 1,000) / 1,000 * $0.0004 = $0.04

Each video viewed 1,000 times:

(5 * 1000GB) * $0.09 = $450 - ($9 free first 100Gb)

So your total is $442.19

Here’s a link to s3 pricing for storage, request, and AWSDataTransfer:
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Comment: Answer above you says 400 bucks ?

Comment: With further research I found AWS does charge for videos views “AWSDataTransfer”.  Which costs $0.09 per GB. So the price would be around $450.